# How to connect Galaxy Spica 2.1 to tv using RCA/ Phono cable

Tags: video-out

I bought an RCA phono cable 3.5mm. Connected it to my phone and to my tv but I only hear the audio that I play.
I wanna watch the movies of my phone on the tv.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

According to the specs I was looking at, the [Galaxy Spica](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i5700_galaxy_spica-2965.php) only supports audio out, not video.

Comment: If you're rooted, it may be possible to VNC to it or use the phone as USB disk to play a video file in the SD card; but there is no video out capability in Spica.

Comment: Ryan: the OP is looking to hook up to a TV and I doubt it can read from a USB disc.  Also, the frame rate for VNC is pretty low - I'm pretty sure it wouldn't support video playback very well.

Comment: there are TVs that can play video files directly from a plugged USB storage, the OP might have one; but he would have to check the manual or try it out. I agree regarding VNC.